# How can we get two-way synchronization in Android using the existing contact list?

Tags: android, contacts

I spent a long time searching and reading the Internet looking for that answer.
I'm pretty sure I found it, but in case I miss something big, I'm here to ask.

As I understood, it is simply not possible to have a two-way synchronization based on existing contact in Android (for now)

While I was looking I became familiar with the Android SDK and for example all the sync management part.

So today I'm going to ask you: DID I MISS SOMETHING?
And because I'm sure I don't: HOW DO YOU DO when you want to sync the local contact book with your service?

I really prefer something clean (as every developer want) but I can't figure it out myself.

**EDIT:** By two-way synchronization I meant full and real sync as user (or developer) will expect.

If any change occur on the phone the information goes to the server and if any change occur on the server it works as well. Any change includes adding/updating and deleting.

I'm aware of the ContentObserver method but the way it works with contact doesn't allow to get satisfying results. It seems that this part as been made difficult by google itself

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you elaborate two-way synchronization?

Comment: giggan - did you ever sove this question?   If so I am interested to hear how.  Thanks

Comment: @ron Sorry I didn't get an easy way to solve that for now, but my question is old and it may exists a solution now. I didn't have time to look up.